# How to force a terms filter to ignore stopwords?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index with a bunch of fields, some of which I want to use along with the default stopword list. On the other hand, I have a **username** field which should return results for users called *the*, *be* etc.

Of course, when I run the following query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "username": [
                        "be"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

nothing is returned. I have seen various solutions for changing the standard analyzer to remove stopwords, but am struggling to find how I would do so for this one field only. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Can you post your mapping for this index and type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like the following: add a custom analyzer that shouldn't use stopwords and then explicitly specify this analyzer just for those fields you want stopwords to be recognized (like your `username` field).

```
PUT /stopwords
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_english": {
          "type": "english",
          "stopwords": "_none_"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "text": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "username": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks for this, makes sense. However, do I need to do this if the *username* field is **not_analyzed**? I figured this might avoid the stop words since it would be an exact match, but I guess not.

Comment: If it's `not_analyzed` then the stopwords stay where they are, but I think you loose the ability to search for just one word in the field. You would need to search for the entire value to get a match.

Comment: Right, analyzer is the way to go then. Thanks!